# Output a boolean in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to write a query in PostgreSQL that outputs `true` if a table is a sub-table of another given table, consider the following example:

```
    TABLE A                TABLE B
   --x: int--            --x: int--
       2                      2
       3                      3
       4
```

An idea of query was something like this:

```
NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM B b WHERE b.x NOT IN (SELECT x FROM A))
```

The inner `SELECT` returns no rows so the `NOT EXISTS` should be `TRUE`, but this returns an error, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to start your query with `SELECT`

```
select NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM B b WHERE b.x NOT IN (SELECT x FROM A));
```

---

I would use the EXCEPT operator for that:

```
select count(*) = 0
from (
  select *
  from b
  except 
  select *
  from a
) x
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use `EXCEPT`. Also adding `SELECT` before the `NOT EXISTS` would result in an error because it expects `FROM`

Comment: @aniani2020: no it does not expect a `FROM`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c80d4e7e18cd6627ffbcdd268a7b5574

Answer (score 0):

How about using `JOIN`?

```
select (case when count(*) = count(a.x) then 'SUBSET' else 'NOT SUBSET' END)
from b left join
     a
     on b.x = a.x
```

Comment: Thought about it too, but apparently I need to do it with `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`